# Magento Add SKU column in cart page and order email template

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to add the SKU column into magento Cart page Item Grid section and order email template

As I am able to see the Grid on order view page with sku column by defalut in magento

How can I use order view section logic on Cart page and in email template? I am running on 1.7.0.2 Ver.

[image: Here this is sku column by default added by magento only for order view page]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Magento email template already includes the SKUs in it.  If they are not there, check to make sure your theme isn't overriding the default email template files and removing it.

Here's how you can add the sku to the shopping cart page:

## Adding the SKU to the Shopping Cart Page

### 1. Add "SKU" to the cart table header

1. Open **app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/cart.phtml** (copy this file from the base theme to your current theme folder if it doesn't yet exist).
2. Add the `<th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>` directly after the product name `<th>` tag:

   ```
   <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo $this->__('Product Name') ?></span></th>
   <th rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>"><?php echo $this->__('SKU') ?></th>
   ```

### 2. Add "SKU" to the cart table item records

1. Open **app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/checkout/item/default.phtml** (copy this file from the base theme to your current theme folder if it doesn't yet exist).
2. Insert the sku `<td>` directly after the `<td>` containing the `Product Name`:

   ```
   <td class="a-center">
       <?php echo $_item->getSku(); ?>
   </td>
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this, but do you have any idea how to add same into magento order email template?

Comment: As stated, the SKU is already in the order email template by default.  If you don't see it there, check your theme and make sure it's not overriding the email templates.

Comment: Thanks Axel for this but I checked that there was an sku of product only and not for Custom option I need sku's of custom option also into email template